# Adjust expression

Tags: adjustbox

How to adjust this expression

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{ article}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8,utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tabstackengine}  
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\setstackgap{L}{24pt}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation*}
\partial_tu(t,x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{l l}
\tabbedstackanchor{\Bigl(\partial_t\xi^t(x)R'(\xi^t(x))-\partial_xG(t,x)R(\xi^t(x))-R(\xi^t(x))\int_{\xi^t(x)}^t\partial_x^2G(s,\Phi(s,t,x))\partial_t\Phi(s,t,x)\,\mbox{d}s}{+\partial_t\xi^t(x)R(\xi^t(x))\partial_xG(\xi^t(x),1)\Bigr)\times\exp\left(-\int_{\xi^t(x)}^t\partial_x 
G(s,\Phi_{(t,x)}(s))\,\mbox{d}s\right) },&(t,x)\in \Omega_1\\[20pt]
\tabbedstackanchor{\Bigl(\partial_xG(t,x)u_0(\chi^t(x))+G(t,x)\partial_x\chi^t(x)u'_0(\chi^t(x))-u_0(\chi^t(x))\int_{t_)}^t\partial_x^2G(s,\Phi(s,t,x))\partial_t\Phi(s,t,x)\,\,\mbox{d}s\Bigr)}
{\times\exp\left(-\int_{t_0}^t\partial_xG(s,\Phi_{(t,x)}(s))\,\mbox{d}s\right) },&(t,x)\in \Omega_2\\[24pt]
0,&(t,x)\in\Omega_3
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please use a complete MWE that contains the ``\documentclass``, all the ``\usepackages`` (and libraries if you use ``tikz`` or something like that), as well as the ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}``. Please refer to [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl) and to [this](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)

Comment: Also, in addition to a full MWE, please define the nature of the desired adjustment.

Comment: The equation outside margin

Answer (score 2):

your equation is too huge that can be fit inside text area. as one solution is break math terms into more line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,
            nccmath,
            amssymb}
\newcommand{\ud}{\,\mathrm{d}}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation*}\medmath{
\partial_tu(t,x)=
\begin{cases}
\begin{multlined}
\Bigl(\partial_t\xi^t(x)R'\bigl(\xi^t(x)\bigr) -        \\[-3ex]
      \partial_x G(t,x)R  \bigl(\xi^t(x)\bigr) -
      R(\xi^t(x)) \int_{\xi^t(x)}^t \partial_x^2G\bigl(s,\Phi(s,t,x)\bigr)
      \partial_t\Phi(s,t,x)\ud s +                      \\[-2ex]
      \partial_t\xi^t(x)R \bigl(\xi^t(x)\bigr)
                         \partial_x G\bigl(\xi^t(x),1\bigr)\Bigr)
    \times\exp\biggl(-\int_{\xi^t(x)}^t
        \partial_x G(s,\Phi_{(t,x)}(s))\ud s\biggr),
\end{multlined}
    &   (t,x)\in \Omega_1              \\[9ex]
\begin{multlined}
\Bigl(\partial_x G(t,x)u_0 \bigl(\chi^t(x)\bigr) +
    G(t,x)\partial_x \chi^t(x)u'_0\bigl(\chi^t(x)\bigr) -          \\[-2ex]
    u_0\bigl(\chi^t(x)\bigr)
    \int_{t_)}^t \partial_x^2 G\bigl(s,\Phi(s,t,x)\bigr)
                 \partial_t\Phi(s,t,x) \ud s\Bigr)
\times\exp\biggl(-\int_{t_0}^t \partial_x G(s,\Phi_{(t,x)}(s)) \ud s\biggr)
\end{multlined}
    &(t,x)\in \Omega_2              \\[7ex]
0,
    &   (t,x)\in\Omega_3
\end{cases}
    }\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

as you can see, i practically rewrote your equation. instead `array` i use `cases` environment (from the `amsmath` package which is loaded by `mathtools`), define `\ud` for derivative, repair all your brackets mismatch in wrote whole equation in smaller fonts by use of macro `\medmath` from the package `nccmath`.